# Using list comprehension to get the Keys out of a dictionary based on values returns empty lists

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of the form

```
{'D': ['A', 'B'], 'C': ['a'], 'B': ['b'], 'A': ['a'], 'S': ['C', 'D']}
```

and I might have as an input two lists i.e., `['A', 'C']` and `['B']`. I want to take all combinations of the elements of those lists, here `['A' , 'B'], ['C', 'B']` and see if they are in my original dictionary and if yes return the keys where they where found.

I have created the two function below in order to do so

```
def func1(r1, r2):
    return [[func2([outer, inner]) for inner in r2] for outer in r1]


def func2(r):
    return [key for key, val in my_dictionary.items() if r in val]
```

so I might call them as `func1(list1, list2)` and I would expect here to get `D` back since it contains the list `['A', 'B']`, what I get back are empty lists though.

What have I messed up in the functions above?

Comment: Have you tried to step through your loops to see if they do what you expect?

Comment: Not sure why you got the downvote. You clearly put some thought into this.

Comment: I used the exact same code for a previous case where I only had to deal with single values and lists, not lists and lists, completely forgot the `if` part, thanks for the help.

Comment: Btw, take a look at itetools.product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the statement `... if r in val`. It should probably be `... if r == val`. In your case, the value `val` will be something like `['A', 'B']`, and so will `r`, sometimes.

`in` checks if an element of `val` is `r`, which will obviously never be true. `==` compares all the elements in the two lists, which is what you want.